# How to get rid of redundancy in a mysql table with lists in an efficient way

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, myisam

Some time ago I made a fast [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) that now has become a more realistic project. Now I'm refactoring and improving it. I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `records` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  .....
  `ref` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `mrecord`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `type` (`type`);
  ADD KEY `ref` (`ref`);
```

`ref` is a reference to a previous `id` or null if none and `enabled` lets me know if this item is the last version of the type. The point is that when an item type X is replaced for a new one, the old one will be disabled (`enabled` = 0) and the new one will set `ref` to the old one `id`.

For example, we have this table with 3 types of items:

```
 --------------------------------------------
| ID | type | other columns | ref  | enabled |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 1  |   1  |               | null |    1    |
| 2  |   2  |               | null |    1    |
| 3  |   3  |               | null |    1    |
 --------------------------------------------
```

and now we add a new item version that replaces item type 2:

```
 --------------------------------------------
| ID | type | other columns | ref  | enabled |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 1  |   1  |               | null |    1    |
| 2  |   2  |               | null |    0    |
| 3  |   3  |               | null |    1    |
| 4  |   2  |               |  2   |    1    |
 --------------------------------------------
```

and if we update the brand new item we have:

```
 --------------------------------------------
| ID | type | other columns | ref  | enabled |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 1  |   1  |               | null |    1    |
| 2  |   2  |               | null |    0    |
| 3  |   3  |               | null |    1    |
| 4  |   2  |               |  2   |    0    |
| 5  |   2  |               |  4   |    1    |
 --------------------------------------------
```

What we have here are lists of item types with only last versions enabled.

But here `enabled` column is redundant because an enabled item is just an item that has not a new version.

So my problem is how to do a SQL query equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE type='2' AND enabled='1'
```

without using `enabled` and in an efficient way (this query is <1ms).

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select  r.*
from records r
where not exists (select 1
                  from records r2
                  where r2.ref = r.id
                 ) and
       r.type = 2;
```

However, the use of `enabled` makes the code clearer, in my opinion.  An index on `records(ref)` is needed for performance.

If you assumes that the ids are always incrementing, you could also use the largest `id`.

Comment: This query takes about double time, but it's enough ;) My discover here is `not exists` I didn't know about it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this query, you need an index on both columns that appear in the where clause:

```
create index myidx on records(type, enabled);
```

With the index, the database should be able to execute the query efficiently. You may also want to try inverting the columns order and see if it increases performance.

Comment: Well, the idea is get rid of `enabled`